# How to install 'stripe cli' in window 10 without installing scoop?

Tags: powershell

I tried to install scoop in window 10 in order to install stripe cli but got an error message as follows;

```
PS C:\Users\sungk> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -scope CurrentUser
PS C:\Users\sungk> iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')
At line:1 char:1
+ iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This script contains malicious content and has been blocked by your antivirus software.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptContainedMaliciousContent
```

I have tried to fix this problem but McAfee blocked installing.

I need to install scoop to install stripe cli but is there anyway to install stripe cli without installing scoop?

Comment: Download the script manually, calculate the file hash with `Get-FileHash` and then add it to McAfee's exclusion list

Comment: how to add it to McAfee's exclusion list?

Comment: and what about the powershell 7?  is it true that powershell 7 can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I did download it manually and unzipped it. and after that, I run this in the right path in stripe.exe

please follow this instruction (if you have the same problem)

- Download the latest windows tar.gz file from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/releases/latest
- Unzip the stripe_X.X.X_windows_x86_64.zip file
- Run the unzipped stripe.exe file